# Are these four similar limits derived from the definition of a derivative equivalent?

Tags: calculus, limits

A classic formulation of the definition of the derivative of $f$ at $a$ is

$$f'(a)=\lim\limits_{h \to 0} \frac{f(a+h)-f(a)}{h}$$

And this means that

$$\forall \epsilon>0\ \exists \delta>0\ \forall h\ |h|<\delta \implies \left|\frac{f(a+h)-f(a)}{h} -f'(a)\right | < \epsilon\tag{1}$$

Since we can choose any $h$ such that $|h|<\delta$, we can choose $-h$ and have

$$|-h|=|h|<\delta \implies \frac{f(a-h)-f(a)}{-h}<\epsilon$$

This can be written as

$$\lim\limits_{-h \to 0} \frac{f(a-h)-f(a)}{-h}$$

With similar manipulations of the limit defintion, it seems that all of the following limits are the same:

$$\lim\limits_{h \to 0} \frac{f(a+h)-f(a)}{h}$$

$$\lim\limits_{h \to 0} \frac{f(a-h)-f(a)}{-h}$$

$$\lim\limits_{-h \to 0} \frac{f(a+h)-f(a)}{h}$$

$$\lim\limits_{-h \to 0} \frac{f(a-h)-f(a)}{-h}$$

**Are they all the same and equal to $f'(a)$?**

If they are, then an explanation for why they are is that $|h|=|-h|$, and thus $|-h|<\delta \iff |h|<\delta$.

Comment: It's more like a question whether $\lim_{h \to 0}g(h) = \lim_{h \to 0}g(-h) = \lim_{-h \to 0}g(h) = \lim_{-h \to 0}g(-h)$ for a function $g$ and has nothing to do with a derivative itself. The answer is yes and the reason is exactly the one you stated. Edit: I've assumed that in the last "definition" you meant $-h$ in the denominator, yes?

Comment: Actually, in $(1)$ you should have written$$\left|\frac{f(a+h)-f(a)}h-f'(a)\right|<\varepsilon.$$

Comment: I have amended the question with the correction mentioned by @JoséCarlosSantos.

Comment: @DominikKutek Correct, -h in the denominator. I have amended the question.